# Undefined method `deprecation_reason' for Resolvers

Tags: ruby, graphql, resolver, graphql-ruby

I'm defining a resolver for some fields, using the graphql gem for ruby.

This is the Resolver definition:

```rb
module Resolvers
  class Events < BaseResolver

    type [Types::EventType], null: true

    argument :input, Types::EventInput, required: true

    def resolve(input:)
      # do something
    end

  end
end
```

This is the BaseResolver class:

```rb
module Resolvers
  class BaseResolver < GraphQL::Schema::Resolver

  end
end
```

And this is where I call the Resolver:

```rb
module Types
  class CommonSpaceType < BaseObject

    field :active, Boolean, null: true
    field :events, function: Resolvers::Events
  end
end
```

This is what I'm getting as a response, using Insomnia:

"message": "undefined method `deprecation_reason' for Resolvers::Events:Class\nDid you mean?  deprecate_constant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty old, but maybe someone will use this information. You should change

```
field :events, function: Resolvers::Events
```

to

```
field :events, resovler: Resolvers::Events
```

as you are using `GraphQL::Schema::Resolver` object, not `GraphQL::Function`.